# How to put Json file into datatables(yajra) in Laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel-5, datatables, yajra-datatable

I have this `Json` file that has been passed into my view. All I want is to insert that `Json` file into my `Yajra Datatable`.

This is an example of my `Json Data` passed into my `http://127.0.0.1:8000/resolution_time_of_calls`:

`{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":205,"recordsFiltered":205,"data":[{"Month":"1","Name":"Analytics Team","Total":"422","AVG":"211.0000","MAX":"212"},{"Month":"1","Name":"Assembly Team","Total":"823","AVG":"137.1667","MAX":"502"},{"Month":"1","Name":"Big Data Team","Total":"5131","AVG":"570.1111","MAX":"985"},{"Month":"1","Name":"Business Intelligence Team","Total":"5706","AVG":"713.2500","MAX":"1127"},{"Month":"1","Name":"Data Security Team","Total":"57703","AVG":"663.2529","MAX":"4463"},{"Month":"1","Name":"Data Security-SouthPH","Total":null,"AVG":null,"MAX":null},{"Month":"1","Name":"Deskside Team","Total":"34841","AVG":"305.6228","MAX":"1498"},{"Month":"1","Name":"Development and Testing`

This is my code in my `resolution_time_of_calls` view

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
</table>


<script>
        $(function() {
            $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ url('getData') }}',
            columns: [
                     { data: 'Month', name: 'id' },
                     { data: 'Name', name: 'name' },
                     { data: 'Total', name: 'email' }
                  ]
         });
      });
</script>
```

This is my route:

`Route::get('resolution_time_of_calls', 'DisplayDataController@getData');`

My `DisplayDataController`controller:

```
class DisplayDataController extends Controller

{

  function getData(){

    return datatables(DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)) AS Month ,Q. Name 
    ,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS Total
    ,AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS AVG
    ,MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS MAX                        
    FROM rtdb.Tickets T
    LEFT JOIN rtdb.Queues Q ON Q.id=T.Queue
    LEFT JOIN rtdb.ObjectCustomFieldValues O ON O.ObjectId=T.EffectiveId 
    AND O.CustomField=15 AND O.ObjectType='RT::Ticket' AND O.Disabled=0
    WHERE T.Status!='Deleted' AND T.IsMerged IS NULL AND T.Type='ticket' 
    GROUP BY MONTH(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)),Q.Name Order by Month asc                                    
        "))->toJson();
  }
}
```

I want this kind of output in my data-tables:

`Month|  Name   |Total
   1  | team a  | 100
   2  | team b  | 200`

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

### Change your controller function to:

```
function getData(){

   return Datatables::of(
      DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)) AS Month ,Q. Name 
      ,SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS Total
      ,AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS AVG
      ,MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,T.Created,O.Created)) AS MAX                        
      FROM rtdb.Tickets T
      LEFT JOIN rtdb.Queues Q ON Q.id=T.Queue
      LEFT JOIN rtdb.ObjectCustomFieldValues O ON O.ObjectId=T.EffectiveId 
      AND O.CustomField=15 AND O.ObjectType='RT::Ticket' AND O.Disabled=0
      WHERE T.Status!='Deleted' AND T.IsMerged IS NULL AND T.Type='ticket' 
      GROUP BY MONTH(DATE_ADD(T.Created, INTERVAL 8 HOUR)),Q.Name Order by Month asc")
  )->make(true);
}
```

Make sure to include the following at the top of the controller class:

```
use Yajra\Datatables\Datatables;
```

### dataTable initialise

I would also include the dataTable load in a document ready listener (unless you are loading the table on a different event):

This would be your `table.blade.php` file (obviously missing a lot of your html but it's just an example):

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
        <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
</table>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: '{{ route('getData') }}',
            columns: [
                     { data: 'Month', name: 'id' },
                     { data: 'Name', name: 'name' },
                     { data: 'Total', name: 'email' }
                  ]
         });
      });
</script>
```

FYI - You only need serverSide: set to True if you are wanting the server to do all of the leg work with the sorting and searching. It can be set to False and still use the ajax to pull in the initial data. However, this is better set to true for very large tables.

ALSO - The columns array - data is the name of the key to be put in to the column. Be sure to put the columns in the correct order here. name is the database column name for when serverSide processing is setup.

### Route:

As I have used a route, also be sure to set up a route in your web.php file for the ajax query:

```
Route::get('resolutiondata', 'DisplayDataController@getData')->name('getData');
```

And your route to display the view:

```
Route::get('resolution_time_of_calls', function () {
    return view('table');
});
```

The above route assumes your view (table.blade.php) is in the folder /resources/views/table.blade.php

Comment: I tried all your answer but it still returns Json data

Comment: What do you mean it returns Json data? Do you get an error message?

Comment: No. It still returns Json data instead of a page with datatables with data in it.

Comment: Ah ok, then you still need to create a route for the view. I will update my answer

Comment: When i use this code in my route it returns to the page but the datatable is empty `Route::get('resolution_time_of_calls/getData', 'DisplayDataController@getData')->name('getData');`

Comment: I don't need a new view because i will put the data tables below my chartjs charts

Comment: If you are using chartjs then why do you need to initialise a dataTable??

Comment: Because there is so much data for my chart and the bar becames small when there is too many data, so I need to use datatable

Comment: Yes ok, but dataTables is a Front-End Javascript library designed to manipulate the DOM with data either already there are loaded via JSON. I don't fully understand what you are wanting dataTables to do for you.